# Remove application using DDMS in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-adt, uninstallation

I can't find option to remove (uninstall) running application using ADT plugin in Eclipse. What I would expect is to have another option in DDMS, just like it has `Stop Process` to automatically execute `adb unistall com.foo.myapp`
If I'm mistaken and the option is already there please point me to it. If it's not available I think it would make a great addition to ADT tools

P.S. Please don't rush to the quick answer - I would hope for one that has some merit to it

Comment: So you are looking for a button to uninstall your app in one click?

Comment: Correct. I want to highlight any running app and uninstall it, preferably with one click

Comment: I will delete the answer if it doesn't fit your problem.

Comment: DDMS doesn't install either, why are you expecting **uninstall** to be there?

Comment: @dtmilano I expect nothing. It seems to be a convenient option to select the app from screen and click uninstall to remove it. Installing the app is two clicks from the project->debug as Android app so I don't see your point

Comment: @Bostone Have you found an answer somewhere? It would be lovely to be able to do that.